# Maintaining a graph and getting path lengths of all the nodes in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, graph

I have a simple system that maintains the friendships of people. for example, something like this:

```
| id1 | id2 |
-------------
|  1  |  5  |
|  5  |  7  |
|  3  |  7  |
|  2  |  1  |
```

Where `id1`, `id2` are 2 ID's of 2 different people, respectfully.

This relation represents a graph where each id is a node and there's an edge between 2 nodes if they're friends.
I'd like to maintain a database with heavy CRUD (Create, read, update and delete) operations that allows me to get all pairs of nodes (n1,n2) where the shortest path between them is at least K (K is a given constant, let's say 5).

I'm looking for an efficient way to save and maintain the graph in PostgreSQL.

Comment: I don't really think you can achieve this with queries only, you'll need some algorithm to traverse the graph. You should probably take a look into graph theory. See this article as a starter http://hansolav.net/sql/graphs.html#traversal